# How to enable WebGL on IceWeasel =)

Tags: webgl, iceweasel

1. Enter into URL 

   **`about:config`**
2. click continue.
3. search

   **`webgl`**
4. find 

   **`webgl.force-enabled`**
   right click and left click **Toggle**
5. verify webGL works by visiting website 
   **`get.webgl.org`**

**Easy =D**

Comment: Please post the answer in an answer rather than in the question. Currently this question looks like it's unanswered because it has no answers!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [how can I enable webgl in my browser on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser)